# I have two symmetric relations on a set. How can I prove that the symmetric difference is irreflexive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I have this problem.

> Let R and S be symmetric relations on a set A. Prove or disprove: $R \oplus S$ is irreflexive.

Now I'm assuming it's not true, because $(x,x)$ can be an element of $R$ without being an element of $S$, but I'm not sure how to prove it. Any tips?

Comment: A single counterexample should be enough.

Comment: I feel like this is a situation where the answer is extremely simple and I'm just stupid but... how can I come up with a counterexample without knowing the contents of the set A?

Comment: x @starfoxa: As part of the counterexample you get to choose what $A$ is.

Comment: Okay, awesome. And I can come up with two arbitrary symmetric relations?

Comment: x @star: Yes. (Strictly speaking the problem should have read: "Prove or disprove: For all $A$ and all symmetric relations $R$ and $S$, their symmetric difference is irreflexive" -- because it doesn't make sense to say 'prove or disprove' _under_ the quantifiers).

Comment: The fact that you get to choose $A$ is not really important, because any nonempty $A$ will work. Hint: What is the smallest relation on $A$? Is it symmetric? What is the biggest relation on $A$? Is it symmetric? What is the symmetric difference of those two relations? Is it irreflexive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. Recall that a relation on $A$ is irreflexive if it does not contain any of the diagonal elements $(a,a), a \in A$.

Fix $a \in A$ and take $R$ to be the singleton set $\{(a,a)\}$ and $S$ to be the empty set. Then $R$ and $S$ are symmetric relations but their symmetric difference contains a diagonal element, and hence is not irreflexive.  Thus the symmetric difference of two symmetric relations is not irreflexive in general.  This gives a counterexample and hence disproves the statement that the symmetric difference of symmetric relations is irreflexive.

Note that if we take $R$ and $S$ to be arbitrary symmetric relations that do not contain any diagonal elements (for eg $R=\{(a,b),(b,a)\}=S$), then their symmetric difference would be missing all the diagonal elements, and this makes the symmetric difference irreflexive. Thus, the given implication does hold in some special cases.